Web Components custom parsedCallback method is not working
Important NOTE: almost all IDEs will defer the execution of javascript automatically which means you might not be able to replicate this issue using them
When working with the Web Components API in a scenario where the script defining the component executes before the documents HTML is parsed, you end up with the unfortunate issue that the element's innerHTML will not yet be parsed during the native connectedCallback lifecycle method. This is because the method executes on the opening tag of the custom element before parsing of its children has begun.
<script>
  customElements.define('my-element', MYElement);
</script>
<my-element>
  <span>Content</span>
</my-element>

In order to fix this, I wish to implement my own parsedCallback method, however, what I have so far is not working.
The idea is that because the browser will parse the HTML synchronously, we can know that everything inside the component is done parsing as soon a "younger" sibling element is parsed.
Therefore, I am adding a mutation observer to the parent element of the component in order to listen to when a new child node, which is not the component itself, has been added.
Furthermore, because it could be there are no "natural" siblings in the markup, I also append a commentNode after the component to ensure it always works.
class MYElement extends HTMLElement {

    static counter = 0;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this._id = MYElement.counter++;
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log(`${this._id} connected`);
        console.log(`${this._id} has innerHTML on connected = ${this.innerHTML !== ""}`);
        const parent = this.parentElement;
        const marker = document.createComment(this._id);
        const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
            mutations.forEach(mutation => {
                mutation.addedNodes.forEach(node => {
                    if (node !== this) {
                        console.log(`${this._id} younger sibling detected`);
                        this.parsedCallback();
                        marker.remove();
                        observer.disconnect();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        observer.observe(parent, { childList: true });
        parent.appendChild(marker);
    }

    parsedCallback() {
        console.log(`${this._id} parsed`);
        console.log(`${this._id} has innerHTML on parsed = ${this.innerHTML !== ""}`);
    }
}

My expected output would of course be
0 connected
0 has innerHTML on connected = false
0 younger sibling detected
0 parsed
0 has innerHTML on parsed = true


However, instead I am seeing the same except for the last console log being:
0 has innerHTML on parsed = false


If I could get this to work, I would enhance the logic by making sure multiple observers are not added to the same parent, and that I read the nodeValue of the commentNode so I can call the parsedCallback method for the correct component in the case that multiple instances of the component has the same parent, so please dont worry about any of that.

I wrote a (very) long Dev.to blogpost about this connectedCallback behavior:
Web Component developers do not connect with the connectedCallback (yet)
Given your wording, I have an inkling you already read that blogpost.... where I mention MutationObserver but don't show any code. (and don't here)
Andrea his solution (77 Lines of Code) I refer to in the blogpost, does use MutationObserver

But the simplest "solution" is:
connectedCallback() {
  setTimeout(() => parsedCallback())
}

workes for me since 2017
There is a snag, doesn't work if your Web Component lightDOM has too many DOM nodes, when the setTimeout still fires before all of lightDOM was parsed.
But should such a lightDOM loaded beast (over 100s of DOM nodes) be one Web Component then????
One more alternative solution not in the blog (there is too much info in there already)
Is:
<my-component>

  Muchos HTMLos

  <img src="" onerror="this.getRootNode().host.parsedCallback()">
</my-component>

But that only works for Web Components with shadowRoot
Maybe (I stopped exploring because even for me this is too hacky) onerror="this.parentNode.parsedCallback()" otherwise
You could use your <marker> trick with this <img src="" **onerror**="..."> trick
But I wouldn't like it, because you are now adding content to my DOM (not in lightDOM or shadowDOM); what if you now add something to my display:grid, causing re-flows, or potentially breaking my code???
I have explored many other options, still sticking with setTimeout
Only once had to add a 100ms
connectedCallback() {
  setTimeout(() => parsedCallback(),100)
}

But that was because a recursive .append() in combo with DocumentFragment adds DOM asynchronously
Never explored how Lit, Stencil, Shoelace and friends would have handled that.
Addendum
Here is a decent playground: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/ovfk7pbc/


<script>
  class MYHTMLElement extends HTMLElement {
    //constructor() {
    //super() // a single super() calls its parent by default
    //}
    connectedCallback() {
      this.append(
        " ", this.parentNode.nodeName, 
        " > ",this.nodeName, 
        " id:", this.id || "No ID!",
        " : ",this.innerHTML.length ? this.innerHTML.length + " chars" : "innerHTML empty! because lightDOM isn't parsed yet",
        document.createElement("hr")
        )
    }
  }
  customElements.define("element-1", class extends MYHTMLElement {})
</script>

<element-1 id="ONE">lightDOM</element-1>
<element-2 id="TWO">lightDOM</element-2>
<element-3 id="THREE">lightDOM</element-3>

<script>
  customElements.define("element-2", class extends MYHTMLElement {})
  customElements.define("element-3", class extends MYHTMLElement {})
  TWO.innerHTML = `ADDED HTML `
  const TEST1 = document.createElement("element-1")
  const TEST2 = document.createElement("element-1")
  TEST2.id = "FOUR";
  TEST2.innerHTML = `<element-2>Nested element</element-2>`
  document.body.append(TEST1, TEST2) // append is new, not available in Internet Explorer
</script>




Your blog did indeed inspire the question. Just curious, are there any other scenarios than when the custom component define call executes before the body is parsed which could cause the components innerHTML to not be parsed? From my quick tests trying createElement/appendChild, and manually adding innerHTML through JS, it appears like the innerHTML is already parsed on connectedCallback. So does this mean I never have to worry about this issue if I defer the script tag which defines the component?

If you create JSFiddles or CodePens I can judge what is happening. And yes, defer makes the script execute after DOM is parsed. It is DOMContentLoaded without having to type DOMContentLoaded.. but you will get more FOUCs, I say define Web Components that create GUI as early as possible... I load them sync in the <head>

I tried to make a fiddle showing what I have tested: https://jsfiddle.net/10gnusbv/1/

I converted that to this playground: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/ovfk7pbc/ (also added above)

It will take some time, tinker with it until you can explain every line

well, I understand it now, but it only says the innerHTML is not parsed on test1 because it has no content. So does this mean I can safely assume the innerHTML not being parsed issue is exclusive to when the component is defined before it is used inline in the html file and all subsequent creations of the component through javascript is safe?

Yes, that's the essence of my connectedCallback blogpost. Mind you, many "gurus" still don't get this...because they use tools like Lit; they don't know what the core technology does.
